# autocomplete not working on one server, works on others

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.10

I have Ubuntu 10.10 x64 and x86 running on various servers and auto complete works on all of them bar one.

The issue:
apt-`<tab>` would show a list of options but sudo apt-`<tab>` would not.

After fiddling with it for a few hours i've found that /etc/bash_autocomplete did not exist. on the broken server. Copying the one from a working one it now works. but still not properly.

sudo apt-get ins`<tab>` does not show do anything.

listing the files in /etc/bash_autocomplete.d/ on the working server has about 50 files, and the broken one only two or three.

i dont think that i can just copy these files though as it might show commands for things that are not even installed.

TL;DR

autocomplete broken, how can i fix it. Seems like its disabled somewhere, why is this

EDIT:
Ok, it was not ever installed...

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  bash-completion
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 140kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,061kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main bash-completion all 1:1.2-2ubuntu1.1 [140kB]
Fetched 140kB in 0s (174kB/s)          
Selecting previously deselected package bash-completion.
(Reading database ... 23808 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bash-completion (from .../bash-completion_1%3a1.2-2ubuntu1.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up bash-completion (1:1.2-2ubuntu1.1) ...
```

its now kinda working, but still wonky... apt-get ins`<tab>` gives `sudo apt-get insserv` as the option. also apt-get install php5`<tab>` gives `apt-get install php5/` not php5-* options.

Answer (score 2):

Did the [bash-completion](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/bash-completion) package get removed or maybe never installed?  Try reinstalling that.

Comment: thanks, it was not installed... ive updated the question as it still has issues.